# HTML string to webview

Tags: android, html, webview

i want to create an android application,

the apk has a text box and one button perhaps.

in the text box the user will input their HTML codes/strings.
and by clicking the button it will show the output of the codes they type from the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);        

    final String mimeType = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "UTF-8";
    String html = "<br /><br />Read the handouts please for tomorrow.<br /><br /><!--homework help homework" +
            "help help with homework homework assignments elementary school high school middle school" +
            "// --><font color='#60c000' size='4'><strong>Please!</strong></font>" +
            "<img src='http://www.homeworknow.com/hwnow/upload/images/tn_star300.gif'  />";


    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
 }

}
```

add this in the menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

call this line:

```
wv.loadData(yourHtmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```